# Como hacer una tabla con una relación reflexiva N:M en SQL Developer

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

tengo que hacer una tabla que se ha creado porque la relación es reflexiva N:M y tengo la duda de como referenciarla. La PK es Cod_Estudiante que viene de la tabla Estudiante y había pensado hacer Cod_Estudiante1 y Cod_Estudiante2, pero no sé como referenciarlas cuando pongo que son FK. Tengo esto:

```
CREATE TABLE RELACION(
    Cod_Estudiante1 NUMBER(4),
    Cod_Estudiante2 NUMBER(4),
    CONSTRAINT REL_EST_PK PRIMARY KEY (Cod_Estudiante1, Cod_Estudiante2),
    CONSTRAINT REL_EST_FK FOREIGN KEY 
);
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Cada sistema de base de datos, tiene su propia nomenclatura, y con la etiqueta Sql, no basta. Deberías de añadir el que corresponda a la preguta. Además seguro que te aportaría valor, poner completo el escenario, ya que parece que no solo quieres la sintaxis, sino un poco de comprensión en como usarlas. [Crear ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Javifer2, fallo mío estoy empezando con las bases de datos y pensaba que era el mismo lenguaje, en mi caso (ya corregido en el título) es el SQL DEVELOPER.

Comment: Sql Developer es un IDE de Oracle. No es el SGBD, sino el entorno que te permite desarrollar con ese motor de base de datos. Creo que en Oracle, puedes saber la versión con una consulta similar a esta. `SELECT * FROM v$version;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sintaxis con ALTER TABLE:

```
ALTER TABLE nombre_tabla
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_nombre
   FOREIGN KEY (col1, col2, ... coln)
   REFERENCES origen_tabla (col1, col2, ... coln);
```

Ejemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE RELACION
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Estudiante1
  FOREIGN KEY (Cod_Estudiante1)
  REFERENCES Estudiante(Cod_Estudiante);
```

Solucion:

```
CREATE TABLE RELACION(
    Cod_Estudiante1 NUMBER(4),
    Cod_Estudiante2 NUMBER(4),
    CONSTRAINT REL_EST_PK PRIMARY KEY (Cod_Estudiante1, Cod_Estudiante2),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Estudiante1
      FOREIGN KEY (Cod_Estudiante1)
      REFERENCES Estudiante(Cod_Estudiante),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Estudiante2
      FOREIGN KEY (Cod_Estudiante2)
      REFERENCES Estudiante(Cod_Estudiante)
);
```